# set the size of the tooltip dialog box depending on the text

Tags: asp.net

How do i set the size of the tooltip dialog box. the tooltip text must be displayed in one line rather than wrapping the text to other line.

in firefox and IE7 tooltip text is showed in one line but in IE8 the tooltip text is wrapped . i.e text is displayed in 2 lines.

asp:Image runat="server" ID="iUrl" Visible="false" ImageUrl="~/Widgets/FMP_Printers/images/status icons/icon_Fault_Enabled.gif" />

```
  if (txtUrl.Text.ToUpper().IndexOf("HTTP://") < 0 && txtUrl.Text.ToUpper().IndexOf("HTTPS://") < 0)
    {
        iUrl.Visible = true;

        iUrl.ToolTip = "ghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghgh";
        valid = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tool tips are not treated the same in all browsers.  Firefox ignores \n "new lines" but IE accepts them.  The problem is not your code but the ToolTip itself.  It will simply behave as it behaves. However you could use javascript to show a div on mouse over and hide it on mouse out.  This would implement a similar feature to tooltip that you could format how you want.